# How can I make an svg circle always appear above my graph line path?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a mousemove function that makes it so that when the user moves their mouse over the graph, a circle with a box on top, displaying information, moves to the closest data point. It all works fine, except that the circle appears underneath the path line which looks really bad. I would like this circle to on top of this line yet reordering and using z-index have not merited success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my mouseMove and draw function, which I believe should be the only relevant code.

```
rrd3.mouseMove = function(){
    var xMouse = rrd3.xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        index = d3.bisector(function(d){return d.timestamp}).left(rrd3.data, xMouse, 1),
        d0 = rrd3.data[index - 1],
        d1 = rrd3.data[index],
        d;

        if(d0 == undefined){
            d0 = d1;
        }
        if(d1 == undefined){
            d1 = d0;
        }

        if((xMouse - d0.timestamp) > (d1.timestamp - xMouse))
            d = d1;
        else 
            d = d0;

    d3.select(".focusCircle")
        .attr("cx", rrd3.xScale(d.timestamp))
        .attr("cy", rrd3.yScale(d.count));

    d3.select(".focusLine")
        .attr("x1", rrd3.xScale(d.timestamp))
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", rrd3.xScale(d.timestamp))
        .attr("y2", rrd3.height)
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    rrd3.tooltip.style("top", rrd3.yScale(d.count) - 10 + "px");
    rrd3.tooltip.style("left", rrd3.xScale(d.timestamp) + rrd3.leftMargin + "px");
    rrd3.tooltip.html("<div style='text-align: center;'>" + d.count + "</div>Listeners");
};

rrd3.draw = function(){
    d3.select(".line").remove();
    d3.select(".areapath").remove();

    rrd3.graph.append("path")
        .datum(rrd3.data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", rrd3.line)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#5a8fc2")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px");

    rrd3.graph.append("path")
        .datum(rrd3.data)
        .attr("class", "areapath")
        .attr("d", rrd3.area);
};
```

Comment: SVG doesn't have the equivalent of `z-index`. Depth sorting depends on their order of appearance in the DOM, so you just need to reverse their DOM positions or, correspondingly, the order in which you append them to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort() function of d3.js to change svg order.
This is a sample code.

```
// draw a circle
d3.select("svg").append("circle").datum({type: "circle"}).attr({
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100,
    r: 30,
    fill: "blue"
});
// draw a triangle
d3.select("svg").append("path").datum({type: "triangle"}).attr({
    d: "M100,100 L150,150 V100 z",
    fill: "red"
});

// Here, triangle is shown over circle,
// because it is positioned after circle.
// e.g. 
// <svg>
//     <circle ... />
//     <path ... />
// </svg>

// re-order by sort() function
d3.selectAll("circle, path").sort(function(d1, d2) {
    if (d1.type === d2.type)
        return 0;
    return d1.type === "circle" ? 1 : -1;
});

// Here, circle is shown over triangle.
// <svg>
//     <path ... />
//     <circle ... />
// </svg>
```